# Showing the equivalence of two different expectations

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, expected-value, conditional-expectation

**Setup:** Given that I have a random vector $B\in\mathbb{R}^L$ such that $B\sim\text{Categorical}(\pi)$ where $\pi\in\mathbb{R}^L$ is the probability vector, and another random vector (independent of $B$) $G\in\mathbb{R}^L$ such that $G\sim N(0,M)$ where $M\in\mathbb{R}^{L\times L}$ is non-random.

**Question:** How do I show that
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[(B+M^{-1}G)\mathbb{E}[B|MB+G]^\top\right]
=\mathbb{E}[BB^\top].
$$
I don't think the distribution of the random vectors should matter in showing this result. Thanks.

**Intuition/Attempt:** If we were to look at the each term inside the left-hand-side expectation separately, we can see that
$$
\mathbb{E}[B+M^{-1}G]=\mathbb{E}[B],
$$
and
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[\mathbb{E}[B|MB+G]\right]=\mathbb{E}[B],
$$
which lead me to believe that I am quite close to showing the expression that I desire... but I can't seem to show it entirely... My current attempt is:
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}\left[(B+M^{-1}G)\mathbb{E}[B|MB+G]^\top\right]
&=\mathbb{E}\left[\mathbb{E}[B+M^{-1}G|MB+G]\cdot\mathbb{E}[B|MB+G]^\top\right],
\end{align*}
where I would like to use the towering property of expectation but can't seem to find a way to do it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have managed to get a reasonable answer:
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}\Big[(B+M^{-1}G)\mathbb{E}[B|MB+G]^\top\Big]
&=
\mathbb{E}\Big[\mathbb{E}[B+M^{-1}G|MB+G]\cdot\mathbb{E}[B^\top|MB+G]\Big] \\
&=
\mathbb{E}\Big[\mathbb{E}\Big[\mathbb{E}[B+M^{-1}G|MB+G]B^\top\Big|MB+G\Big]\Big] \\
&\stackrel{(a)}=
\mathbb{E}\Big[\mathbb{E}[B+M^{-1}G|MB+G]B^\top\Big] \\
&=
\mathbb{E}[(B+M^{-1}G)B^\top] \\
&=
\mathbb{E}[BB^\top+M^{-1}GB^\top] \\
&\stackrel{(b)}{=}
\mathbb{E}[BB^\top]+M^{-1}\mathbb{E}[G]\mathbb{E}[B^\top] \\
&\stackrel{(c)}{=}
\mathbb{E}[BB^\top],
\end{align*}
where:

- (a) uses the towering property of expectation;
- (b) uses the independence between $B$ and $G$;
- (c) uses $\mathbb{E}[G]=0$.